# Is there a way of processing list of number integers entered via terminal without saving them into list?

Tags: python, c, python-3.x, code-translation

I am trying to write a similar code in Python, but I am new to it.

```c
int counts[] = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
for (int i = 0; i < groups; i++) {
    int groups_size;
    scanf(" %d", &groups_size);

    counts[groups_size] += 1;
}
```

Please note that it does not all the save the numbers into memory.

I tried to do this in Python as:

```
for group in range(groups):
    num = int(input().strip())
    counts[num] += 1
```

This does not work. When I enter `1 2 3 4 5` into terminal, I get `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1 2 3 4 5'`.

Is there a way of doing this in Python the same as I did in C?

Comment: you have to use `num = list(map(int, input().split()))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In python, it will not automatically take one number and then loop for the other. You `input()` command will read the whole line at once. So, what you can do is read the whole line in a string and then split it into a list as follows -

```
str = input()
num = list(map(int,str.split()))
```

Now you have all the input given by user stored in the `num` variable. You can just iterate over it and complete your process as follows -

```
counts = [0]*5       #assuming you want it to be of size 5 as in your question
for inp in num :
    counts[inp] = counts[inp] + 1
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I am right that this approach uses O(n) memory but in C, only O(1) memory is needed?

Comment: The memory needed will depend on max input of `group_size` that is allowed. Currently, we are only declaring array(in your code) and list(in my solution) of size 5. That will be considered as O(1) in both case. But if you decide that you want to dynamically allocate the array depending on max allowed `group_size`, then the memory needed will be `O(group_size) `.